# Does anyone know of a soldering iron that gets to 900 Fahrenheit?

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

I'm looking for a new soldering iron that will get as hot as the old Hakko 936, but I haven't found anything. All that I've found have the temp range 200-850 F. Does anyone know a reputable brand soldering station that will go the extra 50 F? It is mostly used for soldering wires (little to no PCB) and the extra heat helps.

---

I have used a 4mm shovel tip but it's still not as quick.

Comment: What makes you think you need to solder up to 482 degrees C ? You will burn / oxidize the flux. If you need extra heat, for soldering thick wires for example, what you need is **heat capacity**. That means a thick / wide tip and an iron with a high power rating. Learn more by watching the EEVBlog: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5Sb21qbpEQ  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scvS2yeUH00

Comment: You should really read the help section before using this site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour  then you'd learn that asking for product recommendations is **off topic**. Also browse this site to learn which are good questions and which are not. That will prevent you from receiving downvotes and closed questions.

Comment: I agree, hotter=more oxidation. It makes it nicer for heat flowing into parts, but everything else is bad. I've also found that high heat on really small wires actually burns them up. Higher heat also runs the risk of exceeding maximum ratings on parts and burning them out.

Comment: Basically: if you (think) you need 900 F / 482 C then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: This is typically used for gxl insulated wire with 14-18 awg.

Comment: Try a solder pot.

Comment: Try searching for "soldering guns" instead of soldering irons.  These can be good for bigger wires.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to use more power with a bigger heat mass tip and not more temperature.

For example leaded glass soldering might use 350W, but for most cables a 65W wand with a large wedge tip should be fine.